# I/O error, dev sda - booting into busybox

Tags: busybox

I'm having some trouble booting my computer this morning, just wondering if anyone might be able to help.

Screen-shot of what I'm getting:

[image]

I just installed a few days ago after having problems with windows getting stuck in recovery mode and am wondering if I might need to replace the hard-drive? 
I had a few problems installing in comparison to when I installed on my laptop and have had some trouble rebooting. I got stuck on `busybox` the day I installed, and then I tried installing again, which I had no problems with the second time.

Last night I was mucking around with some settings to get Warcraft running a little better, I followed some directions off google so it is also a possibility that I messed something up there.

If anyone had any suggestions I'd be really grateful, thanks. I'm really not sure where to go from here.

Comment: To me it really looks like a hard drive problem. Try from live to use the "Disks" application and do the tests there.

Comment: I dont really know what im looking for to be honest. I've never run into a problem using any linux distro before...

Comment: Use a live of Ubuntu, open Disks, then look at the SMART data of the disk http://screenshots.ubuntu.com/screenshots/g/gnome-disk-utility/6134_large.png